# navbar buttons sorting if user was logged in php

Tags: php, navbar

hi there thanks for helping me
I have a navbar and with login and signup button and I want to hide these button if the user was logged in
I'm writing in PHP please help me

these are my navbar and login info code

```
<header class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  bg-gradient-default p-2 navbar-expand navbar-dark flex-row align-items-md-center ct-navbar bg-primary py-2">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-white" href="/"><img style="width:150px; height: 60px;" src="arodanalandscape.png" class="radius-10 shadow-sm"
                width="100"></a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  
</div>

                                <!--  <a style="font-family:'Droid-Arabic-Kufi';" href="team.php" class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0"><i
                        class="fal fa-terminal ml-2"></i>تیمەکەمان</a>-->
                              

                              <a style="font-family:'Droid-Arabic-Kufi';"  href="login-user.php" class="btn btn-gradient-warning btn-round my-2  my-sm-0 text-white"><i
                        class="fal fa-sign-in-alt ml-2"></i> چونەژورەوە </a>

<a style="font-family:'Droid-Arabic-Kufi';" href="signup-user.php" class="btn btn-info mr-3 my-2 my-sm-0"><i
                        class="fal fa-user-plus ml-2"></i> خۆتۆمارکردن</a>

                        
<div class="dropdown ">
  <button style="font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;" class="btn  btn-gradient-secondary  my-2 my-sm-0" type="button" id="multiDropdownMenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"  /> <i class="fas fa-cogs"></i> <strong class="center">  <?php echo $fetch_info['name'] ?>  <img style="width:40px; height:40px;" class="img-fluid rounded shadow card-img-top"   src= <?php echo $fetch_info['picture'] ?>>
   
  <div class="ripple-container mr-3"></div></button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="multiDropdownMenu">
  <a style="background-color: #e63946; " class="btn-danger text-white dropdown-item mr-3" href="logout-user.php">Logout</a>
  <a style="background-color: #457b9d; "  class="text-white dropdown-item mr-3" href="profile-user.php">Profile</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


                      <!--  <a href="" class=" btn  btn-success  my-2 my-sm-0  "><i class="fas fa-user"></i>  <strong class="center">  <?php echo $fetch_info['name'] ?>  <img style="width:40px; height:40px;" class="rounded-circle card-img-top"   src= <?php echo $fetch_info['picture'] ?> >  </a>
    -->

    </nav>

</header>
```

and this is my login code

```
 require_once "controllerUserData.php"; $email = $_SESSION['email']; $password = $_SESSION['password']; if($email != false && $password != false){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE email = '$email'";
    $run_Sql = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if($run_Sql){
        $fetch_info = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_Sql);
        $status = $fetch_info['status'];
        $code = $fetch_info['code'];
        if($status == "verified"){
            if($code != 0){
                header('Location: reset-code.php');
            }
        }else{
            header('Location: user-otp.php');
        }
    } }else{
    header('Location: login-user.php'); } ?>
```

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: sorry but i didnt understand which code can I show

Comment: the navbar code. plus, the code you're using to get logged in user

Comment: ok i will add it right now

Comment: is `$_SESSION['email']` what you set in session after successfully verifying users credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Replace...**

```
<a style="font-family:'Droid-Arabic-Kufi';"  href="login-user.php" class="btn btn-gradient-warning btn-round my-2  my-sm-0 text-white"><i
                        class="fal fa-sign-in-alt ml-2"></i> چونەژورەوە </a>

<a style="font-family:'Droid-Arabic-Kufi';" href="signup-user.php" class="btn btn-info mr-3 my-2 my-sm-0"><i
                        class="fal fa-user-plus ml-2"></i> خۆتۆمارکردن</a>
```

**With...**

Assuming that you have set a variable `$loggedon` to `TRUE` in the event that the user is already logged on

```
<?php
if(!$loggedon){
    echo <<<EOT
        <a style="font-family:'Droid-Arabic-Kufi';"  href="login-user.php" class="btn btn-gradient-warning btn-round my-2  my-sm-0 text-white"><i
                    class="fal fa-sign-in-alt ml-2"></i> چونەژورەوە </a>
        <a style="font-family:'Droid-Arabic-Kufi';" href="signup-user.php" class="btn btn-info mr-3 my-2 my-sm-0"><i
                    class="fal fa-user-plus ml-2"></i> خۆتۆمارکردن</a>';
    EOT;
}
?>
```

Comment: @AroKurd The `if` statement is there. You just have to change the variable to the relevant one in your code? The code in your question doesn't show how you verify that a user is logged on...

Comment: thanks bro but i have an other error Parse error: Invalid body indentation level (expecting an indentation level of at least 4) in D:\xampp\htdocs\ak-group\nav.php on line 82 what can I do

Comment: Sounds like you have your closing "EOT" too far indented. Move it to the start of the line and it should be okay! (i.e. no whitespace before it)

Comment: i did it bro but it still say error where can i send you the code please

Comment: @AroKurd [Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223951/discussion-between-steven-and-arokurd) we can talk here if needs be?

Comment: i cant because i must have more than 20 repi thing

Comment: @AroKurd [Try Repl instead](https://repl.it/repls/RequiredExtralargeGravity#index.php)

Comment: look this is my error   T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE
i just wantedto add some more elements

Comment: Have you got any more spaces, characters etc. before or after the `EOT;`?